# find records with date greater than matching entry in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im trying to find records from a specific records start date forward. Im not sure how to do this. Example

```
Name            Issue Open Date         Issue Close Date
John Doe        02/01/2017      02/15/2017
John Doe        02/25/2017      03/01/2017
John Doe        03/05/2017      03/15/2017
John Doe        03/20/2017      03/25/2017
Jane Doe        02/01/2017      02/20/2017
Jane Doe        02/22/2017      02/28/2017
Jane Doe        03/07/2017      03/22/2017
Jane Doe        03/25/2017      04/05/2017  
Jim Jones       02/17/2017      02/25/2017
Jim Jones       02/15/2017      02/18/2017
Jim Jones       03/01/2017      03/07/2017
Jim Jones       03/19/2017      04/02/2017
```

I want to find each record from the first issue close date and forward, but the dates are scattered. So for John Doe, I want to pull back records from 02/15/17 and greater. For Jane Doe I want to pull back records from 02/20/17 and greater. and for Jim Jones I want to pull back records from 02/25/2017 and greater. I need to pull back records starting from a specific date, but I cant just say where issue close date > 02/01/2017 because I don't always know the close date and the date is scattered.  thanks

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "first" record for a group, unless a column specifies the ordering.  In your data, no such column seems to define the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform some level of aggregation and store the results in either a CTE or temp table before you can use the first issue close date as a filter. For example:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
 SELECT Name
 ,min([Issue Close Date]) as FirstIssueCloseDate
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Name)

SELECT *
FROM yourtable A
JOIN CTE B on a.name = b.name and a.[Issue Open Date] <= 
   b.FirstIssueCloseDate
```